# How do I set an animated wallpaper on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, animated-gif

Well, on Windows XP and on Windows 98 you can put an animated gif as an wallpaper easily.

On Windows 7, when doing that the displayed wallpaper is only a frame of the animated gif.

How to put an animated gif as wallpaper on Windows 7?

PS: If the solution is a 3rd-party software, I do prefer a free solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this to allow use of wmv and mpg as a background in 7.
http://windows7themes.net/how-to-use-dreamscene-in-windows-7.html

Answer (score 2):

You don’t. Active Desktop was removed in Vista.

Comment: It was removed because it was a security risk and WAS exploited.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option in Windows 7 is to use a third party application, such as Stardock's [Deskscapes](http://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/) to provide that functionality.  I use Deskscapes on my home machine and I love it (most of the time).  It does occasionally cause my desktop screen to stop responding after exiting a full screen game, but this is rare.  And I can get it to work just by restarting Explorer from the Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Download dreamsceneseven from http://www.dreamsceneseven.com/
and then download wallpapers what you like here http://www.dreamsceneseven.com/animatedwallpapers.htm. Set you background as instruction.